# Oanda REST API and Java

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

I am currently trying to play around with Oandas REST API and Java and got stuck with it.
Maybe fair enough as I have no clue about REST...
When I try to open the URL in my browser, I am asked to open a file which has the information I want. But when I try to open the file via Java a java.net exception (time out) is thrown.

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Oanda {

private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
static class Prices {
    String instrument;
    String time;
    String bid;
    String ask;
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Downloading data...");
    String json = readUrl("http://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/instruments/price?instruments=EUR_USD");
    Gson gson = new Gson();        
    Prices prices = gson.fromJson(json, Prices.class);
    System.out.println(prices.instrument +": "+ prices.ask +" / "+ prices.bid);     
}


}
```

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. You are getting a connection timeout from the TCP stack; either the `urlString` is incorrect or you have a firewall / network config issue.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I just ran the code on another computer and there is no time out exception thrown!

Comment: @user1204121 have you developed the API futher ?

Comment: @MrPhi No, I haven´t looked into this since.